# How can I add or subtract an arbitrary amount from the result of SUM()?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use `SUM()` in Excel, but I'd like to automatically add 2 to the calculated sum. Likewise, I might want to automatically subtract two, or some other constant number.

I have:

```
SUM((A1:A12)+2)
```

.. but this doesn't work. What is the correct formula for this?

Comment: What about `=SUM(A1:A12)+2`?

Comment: see: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sum.php

Answer (score 12):

You do not add the other value in the `SUM` function. It is enough to say:

```
SUM(A1:A12)+2
```

If you want to add a cell to the sum:

```
SUM(A1:A12)+B1
```

If you want to add another `SUM` I guess you could use something like:

```
SUM(A1:A12)+SUM(B1:B12)
```

Comment: this should also be valid:  `SUM(A1:A12, 2)`

Answer (score 7):

```
=(SUM(A1:A12) + 2)
```

first you find the sum of the values in the cells A1 to A12, and then you add the desired number to the result